# Python logs throttling

Tags: python, logging, throttling

Currently I have a couple of python written modules that constantly log something to files. My problem is that when *something happens* (consider it as a disaster for all the modules, lack of connections with some services or something else) all of them start to log same or very similar (within a module) messages flooding my logs gatherer (which follows to other issues).

Is there any python logger which includes something like reducing the frequency of providing the same or similar logs (it would be nice if got smaller and smaller till reducing the number of such logs)?

Or is it possible to write such a logger by myself? I've been searching a lot but unfortunately did not find any suitable implementation/solution/idea.

Comment: If the repetitive log messages are identical then it should be trivial to implement, keeping a dictionary of the pairs `{ logmessage : timestamp }` should be the base of the idea. If the messages include something that changes all the time, say a numeric value, then some regular expression magic will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I will add required mechanism into the ContextFilter in logging :)